# how to paginate ElasticSearch results using PHP API

Tags: php, elasticsearch

following the example in the docs, I search in my type like that:

```
    $params = [
        'index' => $this->index,
        'type' => $this->type,
        "scroll" => "30s",
        "size" => 10,
        'body' => $json
    ];

    $response = $this->es->search($params);
```

now $response includes 10 results and a _scroll_id. How can I use it to paginate my results? I am looking at this example

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_search_operations.html#_scrolling

then the doc suggests to do:

```
while (isset($response['hits']['hits']) && count($response['hits']['hits']) > 0) {
$scroll_id = $response['_scroll_id'];
$response = $client->scroll([
        "scroll_id" => $scroll_id,  //...using our previously obtained _scroll_id
        "scroll" => "30s"           // and the same timeout window
    ]
);
}
```

but not clear if I have to do a new request or if the while loop is meant to store all the results in a variable and pass it to the template.

Any practical example to show?

thanks

Comment: Are you sure you need to use scroll? How many results do you want to get?

Comment: @DarthKotik It doesn't matter how many data, point of scroll - scroll over data which is continuously changes, so you don't have same documents twice in result set.

Comment: I know, But if you need just few thousands of records `scroll` is not the best way, You can just set `size` in your `search` query

Comment: @VladimirKovpak I edited the question adding some bit. It does not looks like I have to do another request using the scroll_id 'cause this is always the same in the loop, so it is not an identifier for a specific page of my resultset.

Comment: @user3174311 `scroll` it is like feed on facebook... 1st request - 1 bunch of data, after some time (while user scroll feed down) 2nd request - 2nd bunch of data... and so forth...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After first request with `scroll` parameter, you will receive normal payload (_shards, took, hits, etc) and `_scroll_id` as well from elasticsearch. In `hits` you will have `total` number of found documents, hence you have: items per page and total count of items.

To figure out counts of pages - you need to do simple math.

To receive next batch of data from elasticsearch - run this:

```
curl 'localhost:9200/_search/scroll ' -d '{
    "scroll" : "30s", 
    "scroll_id" : "cXVlcnlUaGVuRmV0Y2g7NTsxMzU0MDQzNjY6QnNHMjd0bXlTZ3Ftd1dkblRUd3NQZzsxMDE1NzI4Mjc6ajFzVmtLQUdSaEduRWFRVi1GZE05UTsxMDE1NzI4MjY6ajFzVmtLQUdSaEduRWFRVi1GZE05UTsxMDE1ODAzODc6TURuUG5nbzRUVU9NUUFjSERqM2hIQTsxMDE1ODAzODg6TURuUG5nbzRUVU9NUUFjSERqM2hIQTswOw==" 
}'
```

With scroll you can only receive next batch, you can't jump on particular page.

Comment: is there not a way to do like mysql LIMIT 10, 10;?

Comment: @user3174311 You can use `from` & `size`, but if you use `scroll` - you can't use `from` & `size`...